# Boost converter output voltage abnormal

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter

I use boost converter [TPS61089](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61089.pdf) to generate 6V3A output from 5V power. My schematic is almost the same as TI's Webench's recommended schematic except for more capacitors on the input and output. However, when I measure the output voltage, it is not stable 6V output as shown in the image below.
Is there any error in my design that cause this abnormal?

Solved: During debugging, I noticed the cable connects Vin with power supply had melted a bit, so I realized the cable may not suitable for this high current. Then I changed the cable into a wider one and the problem is solved.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you connect a load before measuring?

Comment: @Photon Yes, I connected it to a light source whose rated current at 6v is 2.85A.

Comment: Quality of switching power supplies depends not only on "schematics", but also on quality of components (low ESR caps, low impedance low-loss inductors). And the most critical is board layout, with all traces being short and thick/wide. Quality switchers can be made only with surface-mount components on a carefully-designed PCB. What is your PCB layout?

Comment: Show your layout.

Comment: Hi, It would be great if you can associate your waveform with the MOSFET switching voltage. The frequency seems to be very low. Your controller may be running in a particular mode... According to the value of your components it can be normal to have a lot of ripple at this frequency.